# Is disarm really a useful move?

Tags: star-wars-force-and-destiny, disarming

- When you disarm a foe, how far away does the disarmed weapon fall?
- Can the disarmed character recover the weapon in their next maneuver
  and thus continue the fight without penalty, except, maybe, losing
  that maneuver?
- The Sum Djem talent is very expensive; is it worthwhile?

It seems like disarming is useless: if your foe wins initiative, they hit you, then you disarm them in your action, but they recover the weapon with a simple maneuver before hitting you again, and so on. If the foe has lost initiative, you disarm them, then they recover the weapon with a maneuver and then hit you as if nothing had happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Yes, it is a useful move considering maneuvers expense**

The Sum Djem talent specifies that the weapon drops anywhere in short range at disarmer's will. And lacking other indications in the rules, this can be considered a general rule about effects in disarming.

So, generally speaking, the disarmed character should spend one maneuver to disengage (in case of melee combat), plus one maneuver to move close to the weapon and one more maneuver to recover it (for all situations, ranged and melee).

That means the disarmed character cannot attack in the next turn (or even longer) if he wants to recover the weapon.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: Depends**

Disarming somebody can clearly be benefitial if the situation is right:

## Action Economy

Let's assume the hero(es) face(s) a group of 5 elite imperials, all wielding blaster guns. Unless you manage to dispatch of one of them at once, there is a good chance that at least some of these will hit with these blaster guns - your facing 5 pools that try to hit and they are not that bad, possibly rolling something like 3 yellow 2 purple. This means they likely hit, and they are 5. So these elites might shoot your troop to smithereens, if you are not very careful and duck to cover...

But there is a way to prevent one or of them from shooting at all, simply by disarming them! This wil force them either to draw a new weapon or to (possibly move and) pick it up again. This might not prevent them from shooting fully, but they still have only one action then: No further maneuver to go to cover or aim for more dice. Under the right conditions, it might even be impossible to retrieve the weapons.

## Capture or Threat

Another spot when you might want to disarm a target is when you don't want to kill or physically disable the target: what better way to show somebody 'I am serious' than shooting the weapon out of their hands? The GM might decide that such an action is enough to make somebody surrender when they have low moral.

## Conclusion

With this in mind, Disarming can seriously tilt the action economy or scene in your favor. Keep in mind FFG's Star Wars series is meant to be cinematic!

Comment: What I think you're touching on, and would like to clarify- disarming is a very cinematic effect to cause. It will be up the the GM how useful it is, but in general it will be a cool moment in a game more about storytelling than action economy. How many times does the baddie bother to pick up their saber before realizing they can't penetrate your defensive disarming?